# Why does Laravel app_path() returns /app/app instead of /app

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am registering a helper function with a service provider in Laravel 10.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {   
        var_dump(app_path());
        foreach (glob(app_path('Helpers/*.php')) as $filename){
            require_once($filename);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The var dump returns `/app/app` instead of `/app`.
I have never seen this behaviour and this not a very custom project.
The $filename variable returns `/app/app/Helpers/Helper.php` when I debug it. Which is a little weird because that is indeed the file I want to require.
What could be the reason for this issue?

I have tried to debug it all the way down to the `useAppPath` function in Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php but still can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: if you have like this: `app_path('app')`, then it returns like `/app/app`

Comment: If you're running in Docker (i.e. Laravel Sail) `/app` is typically where your code goes. Your code has an `app` folder, so `app_path()` is the path to that folder. `base_path()` will probably be `/app`.

Comment: @ceejayoz that must be it!
I thought I was going crazy. So this should actually be right then?

Comment: @Matthias That is entirely correct. Is it causing you issues of some kind?

Comment: @ceejayoz I want to use a function in my helper class in a blade template but It seems like I can't. It always shows up as an undefined function. But I guess that must be because of something else. You can post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Matthias You can absolutely use a helper function in a Blade template. If your helpers files are namespaced (i.e. `namespace App\Helpers\Foo`), you need to use the full namespaced function name - i.e. `App\Helpers\Foo::bar()`) in the Blade templates.

Comment: Any reason why I keep getting the error: `Cannot redeclare App\Helpers\test() (previously declared in /app/app/Helpers/Helper.php:7)`?
I get this issue when autoloading the helper file with composer and also when requiring it with a helperServiceProvider.

Comment: @Matthias Autoloading *and* requiring it in a provider means you're double-requiring the file, which definitely will cause that error. Pick one approach, not both.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not using both. I'm saying that I am seeing the error with both of these approaches. I tried approach A and it did not work. Then tried approach B and it shows the same error.